# 'else' without a previous 'if' C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

```
C:\Users\usuario\Documents\hola.cpp [Error] 'else' without a previous 'if'
```

Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n1,n2, suma = 0, resta = 0, multiplicacion = 0, division = 0;
    int resultadoraiz, raizcuadrada, variablecero = 0;
    
    cout<<"digite un numero: "; cin>>n1;
    cout<<"digite otro numero(si es raiz solo pon un 0): "; cin>>n2;
    
    resultadoraiz = n1 + n2;
    suma = n1 + n2;
    resta = n1 - n2;
    multiplicacion = n1 * n2;
    division = n1 / n2;
    raizcuadrada = (sqrt(resultadoraiz));
    
    else if(n2 == variablecero){
    
        cout<<"\nEl resultado de la suma es: "<<suma<<endl;
        cout<<"\nEl resultado de la resta es: "<<resta<<endl;
        cout<<"\nEl resultado de la multiplicacion es: "<<multiplicacion<<endl;
        cout<<"\nEl resultado de la division es: "<<division;

    } if(n2 == variablecero){
    
        cout<<"\nEl resultado de la raiz es:"<<raizcuadrada<<endl;
    
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Edit: Ahora no tengo más ese error pero el resultado de la raíz cuadrada no se imprime. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Al final de la tercera línea pusiste una coma (`,`) en lugar de un punto y coma (`;`). Si quieres recibir ayuda muestra el error completo ya que *ld returned 1 exit status* no da información que nos permita saber qué está mal.

Comment: ok ya lo cambie pero no funciono ahora este es esl codigo y sigue sin funcionar:

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro. Las ramas comienzan por un `if`, luego puede haber uno o más `else if`. Por último, si ninguna de las condiciones se cumple hay un `else`.

En tu caso usas `else if` sin un `if` previo. Supongo que quieres hacer algo como esto:

```
if(n2 == variablecero){
    cout<<"\nEl resultado de la suma es: "<<suma<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEl resultado de la resta es: "<<resta<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEl resultado de la multiplicacion es: "<<multiplicacion<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEl resultado de la division es: "<<division;
} else {
    cout<<"\nEl resultado de la raiz es:"<<raizcuadrada<<endl;
}
```

---

Había corregido el problema sin cambiar más de lo necesario. Lo que sucede ahora es algo que no viste antes.

Leyendo los mensajes intuyo que quieres que si `n2` es 0 se muestre la raíz cuadrada.

Solo tienes que comparar `n2` con 0 en el bloque correspondiente. Por ejemplo:

```
if(n2 != 0) {
    ...
}
else {
    cout << "\nEl resultado de la raiz es:" << raizcuadrada << endl;
}
```

Comment: amigo sos god nasheee

Comment: no me aparece la raiz

Comment: digite un numero: 7                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                            
digite otro numero(si es raiz solo pon un 0): 0

--------------------------------
Process exited after 5.101 seconds with return value 3221225620
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .